# Latex multicolumn command. Wrap text not filling whole cell

Tags: latex

I am using `\multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}|}` to allow for wrap text. The header in the single cell above the two split cells is wrapping to the confinements of the first split cell.

This is my whole code:

```
\begin{flushleft}
{\noindent\centering\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|}
\hline
{\textbf{Marker}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}|}{\textbf{Age of first confirmed expression (kya)}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}|}{\textbf{Similar supporting evidence from other sites}} & Notable differences in character of evidence\\
\cline{2-5}
&S&N&S&N&\\
\hline
Ochre use and processing&\underline{101}&115&Yes&Yes&Tk1 and Tk2 have more components of the toolkits (e.g. grindstones, hammerstones) preserved\\
\hline
Engravings&\underline{99}&72 - 60&Yes&Unclear&Blombos engravings much better attested and longer lasting tradition; Marillac arguably notational\\
\hline
Body ornamentation&82*&\underline{130}&Yes&Yes&Use wear patterns very similar. Krapina find more isolated/less reliable\\
\hline
Painted or drawn art &\underline{73}&67&Unclear in specified timeframe&Unclear&Neither are figurative; S is abstract, N is semi-representational.\\
\hline
Burial &100 - \underline{130}&120&Yes&Yes&Similar evidence\\
\hline
Burial with grave goods &\underline{100 - 130}&50&Yes&Yes&Similar (apart from age)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{flushleft}
```

This is the table it is producing. You can see "Age of first confirmed expression (kya)" is an example of the incorrect text wrapping.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```latex
\multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}|}{\textbf{Age of first confirmed expression (kya)}}
```

So that your multicolumn is 4cm wide, because it spans 2 columns which are 2cm wide each.

Comment: Thank you! I did not spot that :)